# Creating 2 columns in a div

Tags: html, css

I used to create websites some years ago and everything was made with table but now everything seems a lot easier with div and span (if you know how to use it).

Now I'm trying to create a simple 2 columns layout the first one of 20% of width (left aligned) and the other one 80% of the width. That can be kind of easy but the second column has to show the text horizontally in the middle of the document, not in the middle of that div.

This is what I have now but it doesn't center the text at the 50% of the document and after closing the div the text under it appears like is inside the second column when I already used

```
<div class="centered">
  <div style="float: left; width: 20%;"></div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">This text should be in the middle</div>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Shouldn't your second div be `float: right`? You can see a quick demo here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/D4dL3/1/)

Comment: if you need the content in the center of the document/viewport thats not the layout you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my answer too because I do not understand your request like the other person who responded :

This is a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x77Fz/1/)**

I positioned the left div relatively to its parent and add some padding to the rigth one in order to wrap the text correctly

```
div.R{
    background-color : gray;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    bottom : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    width: 20%;
}
div.L{
    text-align : center;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
}
```

If I understand correctly, displaying the text at 50% of the whole document means you will lose 20% of space in the right of the document ...

**EDIT : I have no idea why I put a fixed height on the main div : [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/x77Fz/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the second div float. Also, there should be some content on the first div or its *height* will be **0**.

```
<body>
    <div class="centered">
    <div class="red" style="float: left; width: 20%;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="blue" style="">This text should be in the middle</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zdTW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

Actually it was simpler than I thought. I just had to add one of these:

```
<div class="centered">
  <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">aa</div>
  <div style="float: middle; width: 80%; text-align : center">This text should be in the middle</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
 <div class="centered">
      <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">aa</div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 80%; text-align : center; margin-right: 20%;">This text should be in the middle</div>
    </div>
```